# Selenium: Get all text with same id

Tags: c#, xpath, selenium

The Xpath of the elements I want to read (Accounting, Business, Marketing, Technology) are as follows:

```
/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/font/a
/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[4]/font/a
/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/font/a
/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[4]/font/a
```

The id for all of the elements is

```
//font[@class='wlCategoryLinkBold']/a
```

The page I am testing is similar to the following:

[image]

I have the following test method:

```
public void ListAllLinksInArray()
    {
        SelObj = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*iexplore", "http://localhost/crm.aspx");
        SelObj.Start();
        SelObj.Open("http://localhost/crm.aspx");            
        SelObj.SelectFrame("content");

        List<string> topics = new List<string>();

        int count = (int)SelObj.GetXpathCount("//font[@class='wlCategoryLinkBold']/a");


        for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
        {
            if (SelObj.IsElementPresent("//font[@class='wlCategoryLinkBold']/a"))
            {
                string value = SelObj.GetText("//font[@class='wlCategoryLinkBold']/a[" + i + "]");             topics.Add(value);
            }
        }

        string[] arrTopics = topics.ToArray();

        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\WriteLines.txt", arrTopics);

    }
```

The above code only writes Accounting (once) in the text file.

If I do:

```
string value = SelObj.GetText("//font[@class='wlCategoryLinkBold']/a");
```

I get Accounting (4 times) in the text file.

What is wrong in the loop that is not printing all four links in the text file. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a detailed explanation, a rule to remember and an easy solution. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//someElement[$k]
```

where $k is a positive integer, isn't what you think.

This means:

Select all elements in the XML document that are named `someElement` and that are the `$k`-th child of their parent.

However, from all `a` elements in the XPath expression you are using, all of them seem to be the first and only child of their parents. This means that for all `i` different than 1 the XPath expression selects nothing.

This is why you get only the first `a` selected.

**Solution**:

**Instead of**:

```
"//font[@class='wlCategoryLinkBold']/a[" + i + "]"
```

**Use**:

```
"(//font[@class='wlCategoryLinkBold']/a)[" + i + "]"
```

**Remember**: In Xpath the `[]` operator has higher precedence (priority) than the `//` pseudo-operator. The way to specify different priorities, as usual, is by using brackets.